# How can I iterate up and down a large javascript array in chunks?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to write a function that takes a large array and iterates up and down it in a set number of chunks via a previous and next button. I have the next button working fine but cannot get it to reverse the array the same way I go forward. Here's what I have:

**Javscript**

```
success: function(data) {
    var body = data; 
    console.log(body.length);

    //body/data is a string
    var text = body.split(' ');
    text.chunk = 0; text.chunkSize = 15;
    var next = true;

    var increment = function(array,next) {
        if (array.chunk < array.length) {
            var slice = array.slice(
                array.chunk,
                Math.min(array.chunk + array.chunkSize, array.length));

            var chunk = slice.join(" ");
            if (next) {   
                array.chunk += array.chunkSize; 
                $( '#test' ).html('<p>' + chunk + '</p>');
            }
            else  {
                var slice = array.slice(
                    array.chunk,
                    Math.min(array.chunk+array.chunkSize, array.length));

                array.chunk -= array.chunkSize;
                $( '#test' ).html(chunk);
            }
        }
    }

    $("#prev").click(function() {
        increment(text);
    });

    $("#button").click(function() {
        increment(text, next);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    success: function(data) {
    var body = data; 
    console.log(body.length);

    //body/data is a string
    var text = body.split(' ');
    text.chunk = 0; text.chunkSize = 15;

    var increment = function(array,next) {
        if(next) {
            array.chunk = Math.min(array.chunk + array.chunkSize, array.length);
        } else {        
            array.chunk = Math.max(array.chunk - array.chunkSize, 0);
        }
        var slice = array.slice(
            array.chunk,
            Math.min(array.chunk + array.chunkSize, array.length));

        var chunk = slice.join(" ");       
    }

    $("#prev").click(increment(text,false));

    $("#button").click(increment(text, true)); 
}
```

Is this what you need? Fastly coded, and without testing so use with caution.

Comment: This works partially but it's  still doing what I've been trying to fix. When trying to reverse it goes forward one more chunk then starts the reverse. I'm trying to get to to reverse to the previous chunk immediately.

Comment: @Mickey That seems odd, I just tested and it seemed to work for me. Have you tried refreshing your page with ctrl+f5 ?

Comment: Nvm I figured it out! Thank you so much! I've been trying to figure this out for a week. I've posted this question three times and no one could help me. You have no Idea how happy I am. I'm still a pretty green programmer obviously.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so first of all I really suggest breaking up your code. It looks like this is a response back from a server. I would in the response from the server, parse the data just like you are (side note, why don't you just return json from the server?) but use a call back to handle pagination.

```
var returnData = data.split(' ');
addPagination(returnData);
```

Under addPagination I would handle the DOM manipulation:

```
function addPagination(array) {
    $('#container').show();
    var incremental = incrementArray(array);

    var responseSpan = $('#response');
    $('#previous').click(function() {
        incremental.previous();
        showText();
    });

    $('#next').click(function() {
        incremental.next();
        showText();
    });
    showText();
    function showText() {
        responseSpan.text(incremental.array.join(', '));
    }
}
```

But to handle the actual shifting of the array, I would use some function outside of your own. This uses Object Oriented JavaScript, so it is a bit more complex. It stores the original array in memory, and has 2 methods (next, previous), and has 1 attribute (array):

```
function incrementArray(array) {
    _increment = 2;
    var increment = _increment < array.length ? _increment : array.length;
    var index = -2;
    this.next = function () {
        var isTopOfArray = index + increment > array.length - increment;
        index = isTopOfArray ? array.length - increment : index + increment;
        this.array = array.slice(index, index + increment);
        return this.array;
    };

    this.previous = function () {
        var isBottomOfArray = index - increment < 0;
        index = isBottomOfArray ? 0 : index - increment;
        this.array = array.slice(index, index + increment);
        return this.array;
    };
    this.next();
    return this;

}
```

To test it, use this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aqc1qv7s/1/).

Comment: Also, the incrementArray makes sure that if you are hitting the top of the array, to show the top most element in the array, same with hitting the bottom of the array. If you want to change your increment amount, just change '_increment'.

Comment: Okay thank you I'll try to implement this version. And I would love to use JSON but the data I'm retrieving is plain txt. I'm using this to build an E-reader app for people with add. It takes a plain txt book url from gutenburg.org and displays the text in individual lines to make reading easier. I'm hoping to evolve it later to have motion-text auto scroll settings too.

Comment: Awesome! Let me know if I can help any more.